Power BI Funnel Chart labels changes/bugs when the visual is highlighted
I'm currently having this annoying problem with the funnel chart visual.
Normally, my funnel chart looks like this:

The problem I'm having is that when I click on another visual (say, an category of my data on the Y axis of a bar chart) to highlight the funnel, the text color and background of the labels change (or bug out), like this:

And I can't seem to find the problem. I didn't find any configuration in the visual that explains this.
Does anyone has experience something similar or have any suggestion on how to fix this??
Thanks!
